# To set limit over selection of Checbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 DIV containers, both contains Checkbox element in it. I want to apply a limit such that
from DIV2 maximum 7 checkbox can be selected and from DIV1 user can select all checbox. But the
total number of checked checbox both from DIV1 and DIV2 should not exceed more than 10.

Each time during check/uncheck when counter of checkboxes that are checked is 10 then remaining
unchecked checkbox will get disabled.

```
<div id="main DIV">
    <div id="DIV1">
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>1 
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>2 
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>3<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>4 
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>5 
    </div>

    <div id="DIV2">
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>1 
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>2 
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>3<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>4 
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>5 
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>6
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>7
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>8
        <input type="checkbox" checked/>9
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show what you have attempted already

Comment: This has already been answered here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes

Comment: I want to apply limit in relation of both DIVs, not on a single DIV

Comment: Why same question is being asked again and again by 2 users ? [__Question__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941930/how-to-check-specific-number-of-checbox-from-2-divs-and-disable-remaining-using)

Comment: SO is not the code requesting service, you should first show what you've tried. Here people can guide you but can't provide you the full code with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var div2Cbs = $("#DIV2 :checkbox");

var allCbs = div2Cbs.add("#DIV1 :checkbox").on("click", function() {
  var disable2 = div2Cbs.filter(":checked").length >= 7;
  var disableAll = allCbs.filter(":checked").length >= 10;
  allCbs.filter(":not(:checked)").prop("disabled", disableAll);
  div2Cbs.filter(":not(:checked)").prop("disabled", disable2 || disableAll);
});
```

```css
div { border: thin black solid; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DIV1">
<input type="checkbox"/>1 
  <input type="checkbox"/>2 
  <input type="checkbox"/>3<br/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>4 
  <input type="checkbox"/>5 
</div>

<div id="DIV2">
<input type="checkbox"/>1 
  <input type="checkbox"/>2 
  <input type="checkbox"/>3<br/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>4 
  <input type="checkbox"/>5 
 <input type="checkbox"/>6
 <input type="checkbox"/>7
 <input type="checkbox"/>8
 <input type="checkbox"/>9
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
//Give you the length of the checked chechbox under `mainDIV`
$('#mainDIV input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

Please make sure that, ID should not have space. `mainDIV` instead of `main DIV`.

- Use `parent child` selection in Jquery to provide limit.
- `:checked` and `:not(:checked)` will help you to achieve this.

Hope this hint is enough to understand.